# How can I check if preg_match() is False instead of True?

Tags: php, preg-match

I have this code which makes sure that the username is only letters and numbers. But the way my code is set up, I need it to check if the result of [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) is `false`.

Right now it says "if secure echo this". I need its logic to say "if not secure say this". How can I do it?

```
if (preg_match('/[A-Z]+[a-z]+[0-9]+/', $username))
{
    echo 'Secure enough';
}
```

Comment: You mean `} else { echo 'Not secure enough'; }`?

Comment: No the else statement is already doing something

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you're asking, since that's what an else statement is for... `if ($x) { //do something if true } else { //do something if false }`

Comment: Rolled back last edit because OP edited the question to show the accepted answer, instead of the original question.  Now it again shows the question as asked.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can negate the condition like this:

```
if (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/', $username))
{
    echo 'Not secure enough';
}
```

Also, your regex needs to be `[A-Za-z0-9]+` if you mean "alphanumeric" (only letters and numbers) as a whole.

The regex in your code would match if the username 1) starts with a capital letter (or more than one) 2) is followed by one or more lower-case letter and 3) ends with one or more number(s).

I'm really not sure if this is what you want. You can do, basically:

```
if (preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/', $username)) {
    echo 'Is only letters and numbers';
} else {
    echo 'Contains some other characters';
}
```

A secure password would be one with special characters and while you probably don't want to enforce this (depending on your target audience), you'd usually want your system to support special characters in passwords.

Comment: this allowed me to register a username with a `<` in it.  This did not work

Comment: You also need to make sure that the regex is applied to the string from beginning (`^`) to end (`$`). Updated my answer.

Comment: This worked thanks!  You actually answered my question.  Yeah it may have been simple but it was still a question.  Thank you

Comment: I still don't get what your real question was, but I'm happy that this works for you. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

That's what the `!` operator is for, so just say

```
if (!preg_match.....)
```

Or this is what the *else* clause is for. Either way, this is rudimentary programming.

Comment: well the else statement is already doing something (going to the next step to check the credintials).  I updated my code but it's still saying that the username isn't valid.  It's only using letters when I try using the code you see above