# PHP - regex check for all alphabet characters

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to write a php function to check a variable only contains characters from the alphabet, so far I have the following code:

```
if(!preg_match('/[a-z]/i', $name)){
  $valid = FALSE;
}
```

It only returns false if there are no alphabetic characters in the string to be checked... What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check If Preg Match False instead of True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925104/check-if-preg-match-false-instead-of-true)

Comment: [Start of String and End of String Anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), [Quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) or: If one [negated](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `a-z`

Comment: *It only returns false if there are no alphabetic characters in the string to be checked* correct. What do you want? Can you give some samples and what it should return?

Comment: Andreas - It should turn $valid false if there is anything other than a-z or A-Z in the $name variable. Currently it only returns false if the $name variable contains no alphabet characters... If $name contains 'abc123' or 'abc!@#' for example, it doesn't turn $valid false

Comment: Your pattern only requires one character to be a letter. Open with a `^` to make sure it starts with a letter and use the `+` to match more than one letter. Then end the pattern with `$` to make sure you match the complete string. Meaning: `"/^[A-Za-z]+$/"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the builtin function http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php for this purpose:

```
<?php
$strings = array('KjgWZC', 'arf12');
foreach ($strings as $testcase) {
    if (ctype_alpha($testcase)) {
        echo "The string $testcase consists of all letters.\n";
    } else {
        echo "The string $testcase does not consist of all letters.\n";
    }
}
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
The string KjgWZC consists of all letters.
The string arf12 does not consist of all letters.
```

Source: PHP Manual

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a start-of-line (^) and end-of-line ($) signs and you also forgot a quantifier (+ in this case).
Your regex pattern should look like this: `'/^[a-z]+$/i'`.

```
var_dump((bool)preg_match('/^[a-z]+$/i', 'foo')); //true
var_dump((bool)preg_match('/^[a-z]+$/i', 'foo1')); //false
var_dump((bool)preg_match('/^[a-z]+$/i', '123')); //false
```